# JavaScript Checkbox Event Handler

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

How can i fire an event when a checkbox is checked or unchecked in JavaScript?

I have a checkbox. When I check it, I want the variable productionState to be set to true, and when I uncheck, I want it back to false. What I have doesn't work. Am I missing something?

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-check ">

<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="checkBox">

<label class="form-check-label" for="checkBox">

Production State

</label>

</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
let productionState = false

const checkbox = document.getElementById("flexCheckDefault");

checkbox.addEventListener("change", (event) => (productionState = true));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for?

```js
let productionState=false;
document.getElementById("flexCheckDefault").addEventListener("change",ev => console.log(productionState=ev.target.checked));
```

```html
<div class="form-check ">
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckDefault">
<label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">Production State</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let productionState = false

const checkbox = document.getElementById("flexCheckDefault");

checkbox.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
productionState = checkbox.checked;
});
```